# Jwt Laravel 8 Exception TokenBlacklistedException not working

Tags: php, laravel, exception, jwt, laravel-8

Exception `TokenBlacklistedException` not working

I am using Laravel 8 and I a'm trying to use Exception: `TokenBlacklistedException` and `TokenExpiredException` but it does not work. returns the following error :

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenBlacklistedException: The token has been blacklisted in file C:\Users\taha\Desktop\API-LARAVEL-8\Laravel-VUEJS\mynew-app\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Manager.php on line 109
#0 C:\Users\taha\Desktop\API-LARAVEL-8\Laravel-VUEJS\mynew-app\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Manager.php(128): Tymon\JWTAuth\Manager-&gt;decode(Object(Tymon\JWTAuth\Token))
#1 C:\Users\taha\Desktop\API-LARAVEL-8\Laravel-VUEJS\mynew-app\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWT.php(106): Tymon\JWTAuth\Manager-&gt;refresh(Object(Tymon\JWTAuth\Token), false, false)
#2 C:\Users\taha\Desktop\API-LARAVEL-8\Laravel-VUEJS\mynew-app\app\Http\Middleware\JwtRefreshToken.php(44): Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT-&gt;refresh()
ion\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Clo...
```

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;
    
    use Closure;
    //use Exception;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
    use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
    use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;
    use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenBlacklistedException;
    
    //use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
    //use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException;
    
    use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
    
    class JwtRefreshToken
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
         */
        public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
        {
               //dd('Taha Suliman Ramadan');
       
               try {
    
                if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                    return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
                }
        
            } catch (TokenBlacklistedException $e) {
        
                return response()->json(['token_expired'], status: 401);
        
            }catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
        
                $newToken = JWTAuth::parseToken()->refresh();
    
                return response()->json(['success'=>false,'token'=> $newToken,'message'=>'Token Expired (So Refreshed)...'], status:200);
         
            } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {
        
                return response()->json(['token_invalid'], status: 401);
        
            } catch (JWTException $e) {
        
                return response()->json(['token_absent'], status: 401);
        
            }
    
        //---------------------------------        
            return $next($request);
    
        }
    }
```

Please help if any of you encountered a problem like this before

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceof` in `catch` block.  `instanceof` is used to determine whether a PHP variable is an instantiated object of a certain class:

```
try 
{
    // 
} 
catch (Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof TokenBlacklistedException)
    {
        //
    } 
    elseif ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException)
    {
        //
    }
    elseif ($e instanceof TokenInvalidException)
    {
        //
    }
    ...
}
```

Anyway, in Laravel, all exceptions are handled by the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class. [Previous versions also said](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication#global-exception-handling) you can handle exceptions in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.